# Como recuperar array do PHP para comparação no javascript?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, array, for

Tenho um código em **javascript** que manda alguns elementos da página para uma outra em **PHP** via ajax e lá são feitas algumas comparações. Depois ela me retorna esse array com a função *print_r()* :

Porém, gostaria de usar o **retorno** para uma segunda comparação somente com javascript, mas não sei como fazer. Existe uma maneira de percorrer esse retorno com um *for* em javascript?

**[EDITADO]**

O objeto que pego na página eu converto pra json assim:

```
var data = JSON.stringify(jsonArr);
```

E fica assim:

```
{"forum":[{"user":"AdministradorGabrielOliveira","tempo":"2017-08-26T16:39:31-03:00","vis":1}]}
```

Depois eu envio pra a página PHP

```
$.ajax(
{
    type: 'post',
    url: 'verifica.php',
    data: 'data=' + data,
    success: function(ret) {
        console.log(ret);
}
```

Alguns tratamentos são feitos e o retorno com a função print_r() do PHP, vem assim para página onde quero fazer algumas operações com javascript:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [forum] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [user] => AdministradorGabrielOliveira
                    [tempo] => 2017-08-26T16:39:31-03:00
                    [vis] => 0
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [user] => AdministradorGabrielOliveira
                    [tempo] => 2017-08-24T04:57:13-03:01
                    [vis] => 0
                )

        )

)
```

**[RESOLVIDO]**

Na página PHP, coloquei assim:

```php
<script>
    var mandar = <?php echo json_encode($jsonTratado); ?>
</script>
```

Então, voltando a página do javascript, eu editei a função ajax pra exibir a variável *mandar*, trazida de lá:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'verifica.php',
    data: 'data=' + data,
    success: function(ret) {
        console.log(mandar);
    }
);
```

E pra iterar eu usei o **forEach** como sugerido pelo colega na resposta desta pergunta, só precisei passar o nome do array de objetos que estava buscando, que no meu caso, é "*forum*"

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'verifica.php',
    data: 'data=' + data,
    success: function(ret) {
        mandar['forum'].forEach(function(indice){
            console.log(indice.user);
            console.log(indice.tempo);
            console.log(indice.vis);
        });
    }
);
```

Comment: Poderia por o código Ajax para saber como faz este envio.

Comment: Mandei a parte do código que uso pra fazer o envio. ;)

Comment: Esta usando json_encode para o retorno?

Comment: Estou sim. Tive uma ideia. Vou postar pra receber as dicas se essa seria a melhor solução.

Comment: Esta devolvendo com codificação utf8 ?

Comment: Estou sim, @AnthraxisBR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assim ele vai percorrer todo o array data e cada indice do array voce pode acessar com o "."(ponto) mais o nome do atributo como por exemplo "user", veja o código abaixo para melhor entendimento.

```
var data = JSON.stringify(jsonArr);
data.forEach(function(element) {
    console.log(element.user);
    console.log(element.tempo);
    console.log(element.vis);
});
```

Com isso você pode fazer as suas comparações.

Comment: Opa meu amigo! Tentei aqui mas me retornou um erro.

Comment: Qual é o erro que esta apresentando?